# Lines abruptly disconnect at random points

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, maplibre-gl

While rendering some lines using Vector Tiles in Mapbox, I encounter the kind of artifacts that are shown on the screenshot. Never before I've seen or experienced a glitch like this. Any ideas of what might be causing or how to mitigate it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided much information, but it's possible that using `"line-cap": "square"` rather than `"line-cap": "butt"` (the default) in your GL style will fix it.

Comment: I should say that it didn't work after all. Still observing the problem.

Comment: You should include more details about your actual style, your data, and a codepen to allow debugging etc.